# 502 Proxy Error when accessing Elastic Beanstalk endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having issues running my Java web applicaiton on Elastic Beanstalk.

It uses a mySQL database which I've go running on an Aurora mySQL service, which I've been able to connect to and use when my app is running locally on my Mac.

I also created an Elastic Beanstalk service and deployed the WAR file to it but when I try to acccess the endpoint it generated I get the folowing 502 error:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

It seems to timeout after 60 seconds.

I tried setting longer Timeout and KeepAliveTimeout values in `.ebextensions/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` but this just causes the endpoint to hang for a longer time before the 502 is thrown.

I've downloaded the EB logs and one thing that jumps out at me is this extract from catalina.out:

> Managed Threads: 3
>       Active Threads: 3
>       Active Tasks: 
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5818f545
>               on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9sm89u1au3ktt1ubpi4i|3c8f06c7]-HelperThread-#2
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3356cf8f
>               on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9sm89u1au3ktt1ubpi4i|3c8f06c7]-HelperThread-#0
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@789ae24e
>               on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9sm89u1au3ktt1ubpi4i|3c8f06c7]-HelperThread-#1
>       Pending Tasks: 
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@32776cec
>   Pool thread stack traces:
>       Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9sm89u1au3ktt1ubpi4i|3c8f06c7]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
>           java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>           com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>       Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9sm89u1au3ktt1ubpi4i|3c8f06c7]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
>           java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>           com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
>       Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1br9sm89u1au3ktt1ubpi4i|3c8f06c7]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
>           java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>           java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>           java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>           com.mysql.cj.core.io.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:202)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:57)
>           com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:122)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:633)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347)
>           com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
>           com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
>           com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>           com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Does anybody know how to resolve this or even how I should investigate it? I'm completely new to AWS and am struggling.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some kind?  In any case, have your configured your EC2 instance to accept all incoming traffic over TCP/IP?  My experience with AWS, believe it or not, is that it's easy to configure.  You most likely have a small configuration problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the instance I initially selected wasn't powerful enough to process my request. I switched from t1.micro(I think) to m1.small. This resolved the issue.