# elastic-beanstalk http request timeout

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a webapp using elastic-beanstalk (Tomcat8 environment).
One of my REST API request takes around 2 minutes (on the server) to respond back to the client. Note that this is a bulk request which involves several 3rd party system calls, therefore, takes a maximum of 2 minutes, which is acceptable for the business (at least for the time being).
However, I am always getting the below error at the client side exactly after 60 seconds:

[image]
I have updated the `Timeout` & `KeepAliveTimeout` parameters inside `httpd.conf` file to 120 seconds and also changed the '`connectionTimeout`' to 120000 inside `server.xml` of Tomcat8. Both of these did not work.

The question is from where the timeout value of 60 seconds is coming from i.e., where to change the timeout of 60 seconds in elastic-beanstalk? How the timeout value can be changed in elastic-beanstalk for longer requests?

Note that there is no load balancer configured for the appplication.

Comment: This may help  - https://serverfault.com/questions/561901/how-to-increase-the-timeout-of-elastic-beanstalk-deployments

Comment: @smac2020: My timeout NOT for deployments, it is for a request

Answer (score 1):

**Check** if this can help you: https://zenofchicken.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/setting-the-http-connection-timeout-on-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk-tomcat-instances/

> There are tons of articles how to set the idle timeout of elastic load
> balancer, how to set the connection timeout of tomcat, and how to do
> it with the apache server that acts as a proxy on each node of an
> elastic beanstalk cluster.
>
> Now the missing part! When you deploy your application into the
> elastic beanstalk environment, it performs a graceful restart of
> apache. Only this graceful restart is not able to reset all the
> settings that you throw at it. Some settings need a hard restart, like
> the Timeout 3600 setting above

**Another user** had a similar case to yours when he selected an instance that is not powerful enough.
[502 Proxy Error when accessing Elastic Beanstalk endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727068/502-proxy-error-when-accessing-elastic-beanstalk-endpoint)